# Disable suggestions list auto-resize on Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, autosuggest

In Visual Studio 2019, how can someone disable the auto-suggestion list being auto-resized?. This:

[image]

It is very very annoying when navigating through the suggested members and you miss-click the vertical scrollbar or another point inside the list due the width was auto-resized... this feature is not well-done for the visual sense of the human being, it is not productive for me.

I can understand the intention is to not occupy much visible area in the text editor when the list contains long member names but that logic is absurd because the list width will be sized to its maximum width if you want to pick that long member name, so... totally useless and annoying for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Disable suggestions list auto-resize on Visual Studio 2019?

**I am afraid that you cannot get what you want in this issue so far. And VS IDE does not have such option to control it so far.**

The purpose of the automatic adjustment of the scroll box is to facilitate the user to visually see the full name of the method and then confirm and use it. It is from the perspective of the convenience of developing code.

**According to your needs**, you need a better visual experience and the best suggestion is to add an option on VS IDE to force maintain the size.  So we recommend that you could **suggest your feature** on our [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)

[image]

**In addition**, when you finish writing such feature, you can share the link here with us and anyone who is interested in this will vote for you so that it will get more attention from **Microsoft**.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your opinion and recommendation. I simply wanted to know if there is a way to fix this without having to appeal to making a request to the VisualStudio team, since I do not have much hope that they will accept my request, nor do I know how long in weeks or months they could take to accept it (and implement it).

Comment: Here is a link to the request I published, but maybe I didn't used the proper English, technical words to express myself and to redact the suggestion: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1065619/add-option-to-disable-suggestions-list-auto-resize.html

Comment: @ElektroStudios Thanks for posting the link. I've added my own feedback.